# CSS: Responsive font-size doesn't look responsive on Safari browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, menu, responsive

I'm building a responsive personal website and I've encountered a weird problem. I created a menu for my website. Since its homepage and content pages have different CSS files, I put the same menu code into both CSSs. It works and looks same on my pc browsers (Firefox and Chrome) but when it comes to mobile browser the font-size changes even if they are same in the code.

This is what the homepage menu looks like on pc browser:

[image]

And this is the inner menu, also on pc. They are identical:

[image]

This is what the homepage menu looks like on mobile. (iPhone Safari) This is the expected result:

[image]

However my content pages' menu looks like this and it's not user friendly:

[image]

As far as I tested I believe the problem occurs on Safari. I also tried Mobile Firefox Browser and it looked decent. I don't have a clue about Android browsers though.

By the way this is the menu list styling code part of my two CSS files. Entire code is in `vw` or `%`

```
.menu-pane li {
   padding-top: 1.8vw;
   padding-bottom: 0.1vw;
   margin-left: 1vw;
   font-size: 80%;
   font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Did you reset font-size on html ? if yes, is it regular value or via calc() or clamp() , else ?

Comment: I did not. Can you give me more info on that? I'm in Web Development for only 8 months, still learning.

Comment: the best would be that you also provide enough of your to reproduce your issue in the question . the snippet button [<>] is here for that. While doing so, you might find yourself what causes the issue. on itself `font-size:80%;` is not an issue.

Comment: Rumeysa is this site currently live? Because the problem doesn't seem to be with the font or setting it. URL would be great if available for further analysis.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the problem. Basically added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">` to content html files and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on your CSS file

```
html{
   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Only works in Safari browser/webkit browser